# Django queryset to match all related objects

Tags: django, django-queryset

Let's say I have a ForeignKey from Coconut to Swallow (ie, a swallow has carried many coconuts, but each coconut has been carried by only one swallow).  Now let's say that I have a ForeignKey from husk_segment to Coconut.

Now, I have a list of husk_segments and I want to find out if ALL of these have been carried gripped by a particular swallow.

I can have swallow.objects.filter(coconuts_carried__husk_sements__in = husk_segment_list) to show that this swallow has gripped at least one husk segment in the list.  Now, how can I show that every husk segment that the swallow has ever carried are in this list?

Comment: If you add a basic structure of the models it might get easier to understand the structure of things.

Comment: But what is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can have swallow.objects.filter(coconuts_carried__husk_sements__in =
>   husk_segment_list) to show that this swallow has gripped at least one
>   husk segment in the list.

No, this is wrong, this gives you a **list of swallows** which have carried at least one husk segment from *husk_segment_list*.

If I've understood right, we are talking about checking for a specific swallow.

So, from your description I guess your models look something like this:

```
class Swallow(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Coconut(models.Model):
    swallow = models.ForeignKey(Swallow, related_name='coconuts_carried')



class HuskSegment(models.Model):
    coconut = models.ForeignKey(Coconut, related_name='husk_segments')
```

If you already have the husk segment list you need to check againts the swallows segments, there's no reason you need to resolve it in a query. Get the swallows' segments and check if it's a superset of your husk segment list.

So we have:

```
#husk_segment_list = [<object: HuskSegment>, <object: HuskSegment>, <object: HuskSegment>...]
husk_segments_set = set((husk.pk for husk in husk_segment_list))

whitey = Swallow.object.get(name='Neochelidon tibialis')
wh_segments_set = set((value[0] for value in HuskSegment.objects.filter(coconut__in=whitey.coconuts_carried.all()).values_list('id')))

whitey_has_carried_all = wh_segments_set.issuperset(husk_segments_set)
```

Answer (score 2):

See [the docs on queries spanning multi-valued relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) -- you should chain filter calls.

A simple way to go would be something like

```
queryset = Swallow.objects.all()
for coconut in coconuts:
    queryset = queryset.filter(coconuts_carried=coconut)
```

A fancy way to do this in one line using `reduce` would be

```
reduce(lambda q, c: q.filter(coconuts_carried=c), coconuts, Swallow.objects.all())
```

Comment: I thought about that (the loop, not the reduce / labda), but it's not particularly elegant, is it?  How about looping through Q objects using AND?  Do you rank that as better or worse that this solution?

Comment: I just realized that I have misstated the question:  I actually need to ensure that all of the coconuts that have been carried by the swallow are in the list, not that every single coconut on the list has been carried by the swallow.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your altered question correctly you should be able to compare the coconut_carried_set of the swallow with the list of coconuts that have been carried.

see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects)

I'm not entirely sure that this is what you want - I guess it depends on if you know which swallow you want to check beforehand or if you want to check it against all swallows - in that case there may be a better solution.

Comment: Oh bother - I have modified the question again.  :-)