# Django: Filter a model with multiple parameters for a single ManyToManyField

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have following models.

```
class Contents (models.Model):
  ...
  tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')

class Tag (models.Model):
  ...
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Just to consider, I am trying to get contents which are tagged with both `tag1 and tag2`.

Is there a way in Django to do something like `Contents.objects.filter(tags__name = ['tag1','tag2'])`

Here `tag1,tag2,...` are dynamically generated.

Update:

I have been using `for loop`. I am looking for an efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a list, then you should be able to use the look up `__in`:

```
Contents.objects.filter(tags__name__in = ['tag1','tag2'])
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in).

For a queryset with both and only both tags, you may need to chain your filter calls:

```
tags = ['tag1','tag2']
contents = Contents.objects.all()
for tag in tags:
  contents = contents.filter(tags__name = tag)
```

That should filter the queryset so that you only have a queryset where both tags match.  The method copied from this quesiton: [Django queryset to match all related objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783747/django-queryset-to-match-all-related-objects)

Comment: Isn't `__in` works like `or` ? I wish to extract contents tagged with `tag1 and tag2` not `tag1 or tag2`

Comment: You'll want to use `Q` then @user24665. Give me a second to update.

Comment: @bozloz `|` too works like `OR`, I tried `&` and is still not working

Comment: I see that.  I found an answer for you that should work.  Perhaps there's not a simpler solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783747/django-queryset-to-match-all-related-objects

Comment: Thanx for the link. Trying to understand it :)

Comment: I too have been using for loop. But I am looking for a more efficient and optimized solution. :)

Comment: @user24665 perhaps try using raw sql: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/. Do some WHERE this AND that.