# Variable interpolation in python/django, django query filters

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

Here is an example query taken from [the Django API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/).

> > > Blog.objects.filter(name__startswith='Beatles')

How would I programmatically replace "name" in the filter above? If I were using ruby, I might do something like:

```
"#{var}"__startswith='Beatles'
```

I'd like to do this because I have a bunch of filters that I'd like to apply one after the other, and would like to be able to loop through these filters (e.g. name, occupation, address, etc.) without listing out each of the queries one by one.

Comment: Quite a classical question and thus asked and answered a few times.

Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/310732/630877 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/1227091/630877