# Django How to dynamically lookup fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I would like to do something like this:

```
before = [ rec.field for rec in all_relevant_records ]

# Do some operation on the all_relevant_records:
for rec in all_relevant_records:
    rec_pk = rec.pk
    new_field = get_new_field(rec, field)
    db.objects.filter(pk=rec_pk).update(field=new_field)

after = [ rec.field for rec in all_relevant_records ]
```

But, this does not work as field cannot be resolved into a queryset field.

I have looked at [How to dynamically provide lookup field name in Django query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227091/how-to-dynamically-provide-lookup-field-name-in-django-query) But, this is not quite what I want.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
db.objects.filter(pk=rec_pk).update(field=new_field)
```

you are using keyword arguments. Which is equivalent to:

```
db.objects.filter(**{'pk': rec_pk}).update(**{'field': new_field})
```

so if `field` is not the name of your field, but a variable containing the name of your field, what you want to do is:

```
db.objects.filter(pk=rec_pk).update(**{field: new_field})
```

---

About this:

```
before = [ rec.field for rec in all_relevant_records ]
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I guess it should be something like this:

```
before = [getattr(rec, field) for rec in all_relevant_records]
```

Comment: Very well explained! Your answer does address one of the two problems I had.  The second problem was how to dynamically get the field in before and after list comprehensions.  Do you happen to have an idea?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Could you please explain it with words? What are `before` and `after` supposed to be? I edited my answer but I'm not sure that's what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you Antoine!  It was a lot of timely help