# Django objects filter by parameter name

Tags: python, django, database

My method accepts a string parameter which is basically the name of a db column.

can I do something like this:

```
  original_message = "Let it go"   
  language = "english"
  ads = Ad.objects.filter(language=original_message)
```

where language is not a name, but a reference to a string? This will save me many if else rows

Comment: Yes, but I searched for a similar question before, and this didn't come up. So I wouldn't be able to pick up the question neither the answer. My question is very specific and I believe many users will find it useful

Comment: Perhaps a better duplicate would help? [How to dynamically provide lookup field name in Django query?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1227091/1324033)

Comment: yep. that's the same

Comment: do you want to update the duplicate question so i can mark it that solved my problem?

Comment: I can't modify what I've voted to close as but I'm sure others may wish to cast a close vote. Glad it helped though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter accepts a list of keyword args so you can just use that to your advantage - coupled with unpacking

```
original_message = "Let it go"   
language = "english"
ads = Ad.objects.filter(**{language:original_message})
```

Comment: wow let me try it. Thanks dude that was quick!

Comment: No worries... I'd rather let this be closed as a duplicate though, so I'll delete this answer if it gets closed

Comment: see my comment above