# How to search in a JSONField for a key with spaces in Django with Postgres?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-postgresql

Suppose I've a JSONField namely "data" defined in one of my models.py in Django. The Contents of the field is somewhat similar to the following -

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "email": "johndoe@foo.bar",
    "last name": "Doe"
}
```

I need to write a queries of the following form -

```
self.objects.filter(data__name="John")
```

How do I write a similar query for the key "last name". I'm not able to proceed since that key has a space. Was thinking of getting the data and filtering it using python, But I think there would be more efficient way to get it done.

I've not real control over the data in the JSONField. So, I can't really change the name of the key.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227091/how-to-dynamically-provide-lookup-field-name-in-django-query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can achieve it the following way -

```
lookup = "data__last name"
self.objects.filter(**{lookup: "Doe"})
```

Answer (score 4):

For JSON field you can use contains:

```
self.objects.filter(data__contains={"last name": "Doe"})
```